# Using polymorphism or not hibernate mapping to Single Table

Tags: java, hibernate, oop, design-patterns

I have created simple design to ease explanation, here is the UML :

[image]

here is the Attachment class code :

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@DiscriminatorValue("Attachment")
@Table(name = "ATTACHMENTS")
public class Attachment {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="ID")
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")
    private User user;
...
}
```

and for the BookAttachment class :

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("BookAttachment")
public class BookAttachment extends Attachment{

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="Book_ID")
    private Book book;
    ...
    }
```

My question here, how can I do the bidirectional relation in the Book class ? should it be done like this? ( it's not polymorphism and not sure if it's good design )

```
public class Book{

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "book", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private List<BookAttachment> bookAttachments;
...
}
```

or  the following :
I don't know yet how can I use the mappedBy as the attachment class don't have relation to Book.

```
public class Book{

    @oneToMany
    private List<Attachment> bookAttachments;
...
}
```

is not using polymorphism in this example good? Book class shouldn't be related to userAttachment. ( The example is just to provide a clear understanding of how the design will be. it's not a real one, so I need to understand if not using polymorphism, in this case, is good or bad design).

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion there's no a correct way... you can **even have both options** implemented in your Book class in the **same time**, the proper one depends on your requirements.

If I have to choose one I would select the second one since it's more general and modular.

But, for sure, in your second solution the name of attribute is wrong! It should be attachments instead of bookAttachments.

Comment: in the second solution, how is the correct mapping ? ( bear in mind there is no relation between attachment and book so not sure how the Hibernate join these tables)